# How to obtain implicit val/def via parameterized types in scala?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, implicit, playframework-2.5

I'm using Playframework 2.5 and trying to make a method that all Json request/response controller method calls to avoid writing `implicit val foo = Json.writes[Bar] or reads[Bar]` inside of each controller method as well as handling basic validation and return the error code.

BaseController which will be inherited by each controller

```
class BaseController @Inject()(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
  def handleJson[T <: RequestModel,U <: ResponseModel](request: Request[JsValue])(cb: (T) => Future[U]):Future[Result] = {
    implicit val convertReq = Json.reads[T]
    implicit val convertRes = Json.writes[U]
    val reqOpt = request.body.asOpt[T]
    reqOpt match {
      case Some(data) =>
        cb(data).map{x => Ok(Json.toJson(x))}
      case None =>
        Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")))
    }
  }
}
```

controller

```
  def send = Action.async(parse.json) { req =>
    handleJson[RequestCaseClass,ResponseCaseClass](req)( (x)  =>
      injectedClass.foo(x.bar).map{ case (success: Boolean,mes: String) =>
        if(success) SendRes(SomethingForSuccess)
        else SendRes(SomethingForError)
      }
    )
  }
```

Codes above can't be compiled because `handleJson`'s `implicit val convertReq = Json.reads[T]` and `implicit val convertRes = Json.writes[U]` says

> No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit
>   Reads or Format for this type.

I've already tried making case class's companion object and put the implicit in it though this does not solve anything.

My question is, How can I use implicit value of parameterized types?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing it like this

```
class Application @Inject()(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {
  def handleJson[A : Reads, B : Writes](request: Request[JsValue])(cb: A => Future[B]): Future[Result] = {
    val reqOpt = request.body.asOpt[A]
    reqOpt match {
      case Some(data) =>
        cb(data).map { x => Ok(Json.toJson(x)) }
      case None =>
        Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")))
    }
  }

  def index = Action.async(parse.json) { req =>
    handleJson[MyReq, MyResp](req)(x => Future.successful(MyResp((x.i to x.i + 4).toList)))
  }
}
```

You don't have to constrain your model with any trait, just enough that implicit `Reads` and `Writes` exists.

To ensure that, it is nice to have your `Reads` and `Writes` defined in companion object of your class. You will bring them to implicit scope when you import your model classes.

```
object MyReq {
  implicit val myReqReads: Reads[MyReq] = Json.reads[MyReq]
}
case class MyReq(i: Int)

object MyResp {
  implicit val myRespWrites: Writes[MyResp] = Json.writes[MyResp]
}
case class MyResp(l: List[Int])
```

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize `implicit` variable before invoke `handleJson` and set `convertReq` with `convertRes` to implicit method parameters for `handleJson`:

```
def send = Action.async(parse.json) { req =>
    implicit val convertReq = Json.reads[RequestCaseClass]
    implicit val convertRes = Json.writes[ResponseCaseClass]
    handleJson[RequestCaseClass,ResponseCaseClass](req)( (x)  =>
      injectedClass.foo(x.bar).map{ case (success: Boolean,mes: String) =>
        if(success) SendRes(SomethingForSuccess)
        else SendRes(SomethingForError)
      }
    )
}

def handleJson[T <: RequestModel,U <: ResponseModel](request: Request[JsValue])(cb: (T) => Future[U])(implicit convertReq: Reads, convertRes: Writes):Future[Result] = {
    val reqOpt = request.body.asOpt[T]
    reqOpt match {
      case Some(data) =>
        cb(data).map{x => Ok(Json.toJson(x))}
      case None =>
        Future(Ok(Json.obj("foo" -> "bar")))
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if multiple implicit parameter like you did `(implicit a: T)(implicit b: T)` works or not. Is it supposed to be `(implicit a: Reads, b: Writes)`?

Comment: works perfectly with `(implicit a: Reads, b: Writes)`.
I still need to write reads and writes for each controller though.

Comment: @suish You could just use `Json.format[ResponseCaseClass]`, to merge together writes and reads. Never use `Future.apply` when you don't need async as its going to put a new runnable onto the ThreadPool. The last line should be `Future.successful(Ok(Json.obj(...))` which will correctly produce a `ConstFuture`.

Comment: @flavian Thanks for the comment. fixed the question.
There are 2 case classes in here, one for reads(request) and the latter one for writes(response).

Comment: I usually put all my `implicit val` in a package object. This way, the compiler only runs the macro code (potentially lengthy) once, and the implicits are automatically available everywhere.